# Stop File Replication Services

Tags: windows-server-2003, dfs, file-replication-services

I am running File Replication Services on Windows 2003 on Server A. This replicates with a few other branches.

Basically, I need to stop A from replicating, but without making the change in DFS management (for some reason, it gives me an error when trying to look at the replication folders saying `The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted`).

I want the users at the branch to not have to re-point their mapped drives/shares. How can I go about this? Is FRS a service that can be stopped from services?

I was thinking about modifying the permissions on the share, and although this stopped replication, I assume that those at the local branch will not be able to access it anymore.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I've stopped the File Replication Service and this appears to have done it.

Answer (score 1):

Stopping the File Replication Service did what I wanted.

Comment: How does this not answer my question? My question was basically "How do I stop replication"- stopping the service did that.